# Auto generate IDs from name and surname

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of email names such as this:

- Name.Surname@domain.com
- Anothername.Anothersurname@domain.com

I'm trying to figure out an excel formula, that would do the following:

- John.Doe@domain.com would be translated into an ID - JD
- Nick.Doe@domain.com would be translated into an ID - ND

However, I want to make sure if there's a John.Doe and a Jane.Doe, that they'd get ID's that aren't the same (so for example it would be JD1 and JD2). 
So essentially, I don't want to have two JD, but JD1 and JD2.
How would I achieve that with excel?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with what you've tried so far?

Comment: I've tried splitting the string by the dot - so John.Doe would become JD, but I couldn't figure out to make sure it's unique

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with the *formula* you've tried so far? You can use COUNTIF to test if the ID is unique.

Comment: I was able to split them into JD, but couldn't figure out what to do from there. Thankfully Scott helped me!

Comment: Yes, Scott's answer is great. Just a note, I downvoted your question because you didn't share the *formula* you tried. If you're asking a question about a formula, best to share the formula you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
=UPPER(LEFT(A1)&MID(A1,FIND(".",A1)+1,1))&TEXT(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,LEFT(A1)&"*"&"."&MID(A1,FIND(".",A1)+1,1)&"*"),"00")
```

this will always put a two digit number behind the initials, regardless of number of employees with those initials.

[image]